# Let .mouseover work only first time you roll over

Tags: javascript, mouseover, effect

In javascript, I want to make a rule so that .mouseover will only have effect in the first time you roll over.

How can I do that ?

Here's my code:

```
$("#page3").mouseover(function(){
$("#htmlcss").animate({width: "90%"}, 500);
$("#jqueryjavascript").animate({width: "40%"}, 500);
$("#phpmysql").animate({width: "20%"}, 500); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the unbind method of jquery - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Just call the unbind method on the object inside the mouseover event handler and it should work.

Here's an example:

```
$('div').mouseover( function(event){  
    $(this).append('<br>Hi again!');  
    $(this).unbind(event);  
});
```

I think your code should be changed to something like this:

```
$("#page3").mouseover(function(event){  
    $("#htmlcss").animate({width: "90%"}, 500);  
    $("#jqueryjavascript").animate({width: "40%"}, 500);  
    $("#phpmysql").animate({width: "20%"}, 500);  
    $(this).unbind(event);  
});
```